# Azure Pipeline runs not automatically deleting

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have two build YAML pipelines to run tests on TFS one for front-end and one for back-end tests. We use two self-hosted windows agents to run these builds and we are on Azure DevOps Server 2020. Ever since we started running the pipeline we noticed our TFS database size ballooning up. We've tried editing our retention settings to only keep the most recent builds but they are still saved no matter what we change.

Below are our retention settings:

**Collection Settings**

[image]

**Project Pipeline Settings**

[image]

**Project Pipeline Release Retention:**

[image]

**EDIT: Test Retention Settings:**

[image]

**END EDIT**

Our YAML pipelines don't have any specific retention settings so my understanding would be that it defaults to the project pipeline settings. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. We have runs that go as far back as November, which is when we first created the pipelines. I can also manually check which builds are and aren't retained:

**Example of retained build**
[image]
[image]

**Example of not retained build**
[image]
[image]

However, these runs are just never getting deleted. Is my understanding of how retention works just incorrect and the builds shouldn't be getting automatically deleted by TFS? Or do I need to change my Azure DevOps settings somehow to automatically delete the builds once the retention settings no longer apply to it?

It's also worth mentioning we do have a release pipeline, although we've been experiencing these problems since way before we created it and the release pipeline only has dependencies on master but no feature runs are getting deleted either.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970547/azure-devops-server-2019-retention-policy-no-longer-working/60320828#60320828) SO post that seems to only apply to classic UI pipeline editor. Is there a way I can apply this to my YAML pipeline?

**Edit 2**

So I did make some more progress on this. I wrote a script that would delete all the runs that weren't held by retention settings:

```
$token = "{PAT}"
$url="https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/?api-version=6.0"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

ForEach( $build in $response.value )
{
    if ((-not $build.keepForever) -and (-not $build.retainedByRelease)) {
        $url="https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$($build.id)?api-version=6.0"
        $deleteResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Delete -ContentType application/json
        Write-Host "Deleted" $url
    }
}
```

This deletes all the runs just fine. However, from what I can tell in the docs, this should happen automatically by TFS. Are there any event log sources I could filter for or any specific times of day to check that may lead me to where the actual deletion of the runs should be taking place?

Comment: Could you check this documentation and follow the steps to see whether it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml?

Comment: So we did go through that documentation but it still doesn't seem to work. It gives four conditions that need to be met for a run to be deleted and it seems like most runs meet all of them. 
1. Enough time has passed is definitely met since we have runs over 4 months old.
2. It isn't a recent run on a saved branch because most runs are not on master. 
3. They aren't marked by anyone to be kept. 
4. They aren't retained by a release pipeline because this has been happening since before we implemented a release pipeline.

Comment: Could you try in other team projects? Also, go the the server machine to check the event log in Event Viewer, to see whether there is useful information.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have any other projects with pipelines that we can test with. I also tried to view the event logs but couldn't see anything that stuck out as unusual. One potential issue is that we did make changes to the retention policies after creating the pipelines originally. Could that be causing these problems?

Comment: I don't think this would cause this issue. You may try a new project to see whether you could reproduce this issue.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. Unfortunately I am unable to create a new project to test this, I just don't have the permission within my organization. If that is the only way to resolve this I'll probably just need to add a manual script to remove runs regularly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem was fixed in the [Azure DevOps 2020.0.1 Patch 2 Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-202001-patch-2-release-date-april-13-2021). I recommend looking at [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-server-2020-retention-policy-not-work/1306205) in detail to see whether the solution applies in your case.