# Triggering Azure Pipelines Build Deletion

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am tasked to verify why expired builds are not deleted in my company's locally hosted Azure DevOps server.

When querying the SQL Database I find that there are very few deleted builds and most of those were manually triggered.

Most of the builds aren't actively retained.[image]

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891132/azure-pipeline-runs-not-automatically-deleting) which asks pretty much the same question I am asking but does not seem to have an answer. To me it looks like there is an infrequently found bug for cases like this, which has not yet been diagnosed. My question is: is there a way, for instance via REST API to trigger the deletion of Builds as defined via the DevOps Admin interface?

On further review, I discovered that what actually seems to be happening is that DevOps, though updated to the latest release, seems to be applying per-Pipeline rules. One of the pipelines has this custom rule: [image: Custom Rule] and I have evidence that tells me that the builds are being deleted as per that rule.

Comment: Can you check retention leases for those builds?

Comment: It's pretty much like the other question. A few are retained, but most of them aren't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Developer Community at Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-server-2020-retention-policy-not-work/1306205). Seems to have been a problem that was fixed in their [2020.0.1 Patch 2 Release](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-server-2020-retention-policy-not-work/1306205). I should note, however, that even though the issue is officially closed, there have been a couple of dissenting votes as of this date.